# Counting the first letters of names in a list

Tags: ios, arrays, function, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to create a function which takes a list as an argument, and returns the type of first-letters the names as a list, and the quantity of those letters, for example, if my list looks like this:

```
let thisList:[String] = ["Roman", "Serial", "Thomas", "Peter", "Pan", "Other", "Peter", "Remy"]
```

I expect the output of my function to look like this:

```
["r": 2, "o": 1, "p": 3, "s": 1, "t": 1]
```

My function currently looks like this:

```
func listCounter(usernames: [String])->Dictionary<String,Int>{

    var countDict : [ String : Int ] = [:]
    var list = [String](countDict.keys)

    for user in usernames{

        let index = advance(user.startIndex, 0)

        //Retrieving the first letter of the name and converting it to a string
        var letter = "\(user[index])" as String
        letter = letter.lowercaseString

        //Checking if the list already has the letter in it
        if (find(list, letter) == nil){
            countDict[letter] = 1
            println("Letter not found, not appended")
        //If the letter is in the list, add its current value to 1
        }else{
            let number = Int(countDict[letter]!)
            countDict[letter] = number + 1
        }
    }
    return countDict
}
```

but for some reason it won't add the letters in my else-statement, and only returns:

```
["r": 1, "o": 1, "p": 1, "s": 1, "t": 1]
```

and I can't figure out why.

If anyone can see why, or has a better solution to my problem, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not a good swift reader, but shouldn't you, in the if branch, add the letter to list?  list appears to me to remain empty unconditionally

Comment: yeah as danh said, list is always empty and never appended to

Comment: Instead of `var list = [String](countDict.keys)`  use dict `var firstCount = [String:Int]()`to count the occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

An `NSCountedSet` can help you here.  In fact you could just return an `NSCountedSet` and skip the creation of the dictionary at the end.

```
func listCounter(usernames: [String])->Dictionary <String,Int> {

    let countedSet=NSCountedSet()

    for user in usernames{

        let index = user.substringToIndex(advance(user.startIndex,1))

        countedSet.addObject(index.lowercaseString)
    }

    var dict=Dictionary<String,Int>()

    let letters = countedSet.objectEnumerator().allObjects as [String]

    for letter in letters {
        dict[letter]=countedSet.countForObject(letter)
    }

    return dict
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also utilize map-reduce to generate your output

```
let thisList = ["Roman", "Serial", "Thomas", "Peter", "Pan", "Other", "Peter", "Remy"]

func firstLetterCountOfList(list: [String]) -> [String:Int] {

    let mappingFunction = {  (x: String) -> String in
            let index = advance(x.startIndex, 0)
            return String(x[index]).lowercaseString
    }

    let reducingFunction = { (x:[String:Int], y:String) -> [String:Int] in
        var output = x
        if let count = output[y] {
            output[y] = count + 1
        }
        else {
            output[y] = 1
        }

        return output
    }

    return list.map(mappingFunction).reduce([:], reducingFunction)
}

firstLetterCountOfList(thisList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can further decrease the code from the already given solution of using `reduce` using nil coalescing operator. http://www.codingexplorer.com/nil-coalescing-swift/

`successor` function gets the successor to the element. if the element is 1 it returns 2.

```
let thisList = ["Roman", "Serial", "Thomas", "Peter", "Pan", "Other", "Peter", "Remy"]

func firstLetterCountOfList(list: [String]) -> [String:Int] {

    return list.reduce([:], { (var letterCount, name) -> [String:Int] in

        //Create the range to get first character.
        let range = advance(name.startIndex, 0)

        //Extract the first character here.
        let char = String(name[range]).lowercaseString

        /* This sets the character count to 1 if the char does
        not exist in the dictionary. ?? is nil coalescing operator.*/

        letterCount[char] = letterCount[char]?.successor() ?? 1 

        return letterCount
    })
}
```